# If $aH = Hb$ for all $a,b \in G$, prove that $aH = Ha$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If it holds for all $a, b \in G$ then substitute $b = a$ and the result follows.

Right?! This was an old exam question; I've been staring at it for a while now and I simply can't believe it's that simple. Am I missing something here?

Comment: It is indeed that simple.

Comment: Moreover, $H=G$.

Comment: Think about it this way. Imagine a function defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that has two heights, $1$ and $0$, representing "True" and "False." Suppose that function equals 1 everywhere. Then it certainly equals 1 on the main diagonal. Now replace $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $G$ (you can't really visualize it anymore, but the concept is the same) and let $f(a,b) = 1$ iff $aH=Hb.$ The theorem you're given tells you that this function equals $1$ everywhere on $G^2$. So it certainly equal $1$ on the main diagonal. But this just means that $aH=Ha$ for all $a \in G$.

Comment: I forgot to thank you -- thank you for your insightful comments.

Comment: A much better question is, if $aH=Hb$ for **some** $a$ and $b$ in $G$, then $aH=Ha$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If $aH = Hb$ for all $a,b \in G$, prove that $aH = Ha$.

This might have been a *warm-up* question from the old exam. Indeed, it is as simple as what you wrote. If $aH = Hb$ for all $a, b \in G$, then it holds also for $a = b$, giving us the desired conclusion $$a H = Ha$$

---

Exercise: Conclude that $H = G$.

Comment: We know, in general, that $aH = H \iff a \in H$. Suppose that $H \varsubsetneq G$. Then there exists a $g \in G\backslash H$, which implies that $gH \neq H = He$, which contradicts our statement that it should hold for all $a,b \in G$.

Comment: @svd Excellent! Nice and concise argument.

Comment: @amWhy: Nice question and response +1

Comment: @amWhy Thank you! And thanks for your exercise. At first I had attempted a direct proof but I got stuck somewhere -- I think I have it now, though: Suppose $aH = Hb \quad \forall a,b \in G$. Then there exists a $h \in H$ such that $a = hb$, which implies that $a \in Hb$. By multiplying by $b^{-1}$ on the right, we have $ab^{-1} \in H$. If $b = e$ is substituted, then $a \in H$. Since $a$ is a random element of $G$, we have that $G \subseteq H$. $H \subseteq G$ follows per definition.

Comment: @amWhy + great work ;)